# What are the options to scale up/scale down a kubernetes statefulset during runtime?

Tags: kubernetes, scale, kubernetes-helm

In my use case i need to scale up a stateful set upon specific logic, and scale it down.
I'm not sure HPA will help as i need to create exactly one replica each time, and later raise a notification to scale it down, meaning - the application will be scaled, and then for a specific amount of time there will be no scaling down (HPA will continue spinning pods until its conditions are met, if they are met, it will scale down the pod which is a problem).

I'm deploying using helm.

Should i:

- Make the pod access K8s API and change the replica count?
- Use helm controller to maybe create/update a CRD that contains the replica count?
- run kubectl scale inside the pod when the conditions are met?

what's the best practices here?

Comment: I'm not an expert but if it should be scaled up/down programatically, sounds like using the API would be the way to go. Using kubectl scale would probably involve installing kubectl on the pod - that doesn't seem elegant & would increase pod size - but if you're in a rush, it'd work as a hacky solution

Comment: I just wonder how clean it is, as when updating the deployment (during cicd upgrade pipeline) i will need to also adjust the current number of replicas that were changed dynamically, i wonder if thats clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) that will spawn a pod each (x minutes) and check, for example by using [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) if it needs to scale up/down the [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/).

This `Job` will use the [REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/), with it you can use [API reference docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/) to [`Replace`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#replace-scale-replicationcontroller-v1-core) or [`Patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#patch-scale-replicationcontroller-v1-core) your StatefulSet.

You can do that by:

[Using kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#using-kubectl-proxy)

> `$ kubectl proxy --port=8080 &`
>   See [kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands/#proxy) for more details.
>
> Then you can explore the API with curl, wget, or a browser, like so:
>
> `$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/`
>   The output is similar to this:

```
{
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.0.1.149:443"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Without kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy)

> It is possible to avoid using kubectl proxy by passing an authentication token directly to the API server, like this:
>
> Using  `grep/cut`  approach:

```sh
# Check all possible clusters, as you .KUBECONFIG may have multiple contexts:
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{"Cluster name\tServer\n"}{range .clusters[*]}{.name}{"\t"}{.cluster.server}{"\n"}{end}'

# Select name of cluster you want to interact with from above output:
export CLUSTER_NAME="some_server_name"

# Point to the API server refering the cluster name
APISERVER=$(kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name==\"$CLUSTER_NAME\")].cluster.server}")

# Gets the token value
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secrets -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations['kubernetes\.io/service-account\.name']=='default')].data.token}"|base64 -d)

# Explore the API with TOKEN
curl -X GET $APISERVER/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

> The output is similar to this:

```
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.0.1.149:443"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or with programmatic access to the API, Kubernetes officially supports [Go](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#go-client) and [Python](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#python-client) client libraries.

I hope this helps you a bit, if you have further questions please ask.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing it in a custom way, but thanks! i'll accept this :)